# Custom Form title & input field do not line up

Tags: 2013, custom-form

I am using Sharepoint 2013 OP with SPD 2013.

I have created a custom form, then saved it as a webpart. I inserted the WebPart onto a blank page. When I open the page, the titles do not line up with the input fields. I have attached a photo as an example. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Example]

Comment: is that XSLT based dataform webpart? or HTML  form?

Comment: I believe it's XSLT. I'm not sure how you check?

Comment: ok , if you have not written HTML form, then it  xslt

Comment: Yes sorry. Somewhat new to this. Could it be the spellchecker icon pushing the titles down?

Comment: Could be...will have to check DOM through toolbar to see whats causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XSLT based custom form, you have two options, choose as per your skills

1. Add CSS/Modify XSLT in dataform webpart itself. For this, open page in sharepoint desinger and edit in advance Mode. You should see these two fields. Add CSS to fix the alignment. Below links might help,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UqyOihqavE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx1vwCBVo64

2. Add script editor on the page and target these Titles using CSS and fix its alignment

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0YaOE8Byv4 (this shows how to add webpart and then you can add your CSS)

Comment: Ok I'm in the webpart in SPD. What should i be lookking for to change the alignment?

Comment: Look for ms-vb class i think...and add CSS with margin/padding... you will have to inspect title element in browser and figure how much of padding/margin needs to be added

Comment: Do you know how to remove the spell check button?

Comment: I fixed it by changing the alignment of each text. Seemed to override whatever was doing that. Thanks for your help Rohit!

Comment: okay,...that works too..if it helped can you please mark it as answer or add you own answer